# CSS Style Help needed

Tags: css

I my website I am few font-sizes but with different colors and different paddings und margins.

for example

```
    h5 {
         color: #ED1B34;
         font-size: 1.1em;
         font-weight: bold;
         margin-bottom: 0.6em; 
}
```

i want to write such tags independent of margins and paddings.

what will be the best practice to declare padding and margins. As this

> h5

Tag may have 10 different margin setting in the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practise is to define non-margin attributes for H5 generally:

```
h5 {
     color: #ED1B34;
     font-size: 1.1em;
     font-weight: bold;
}
```

And then provide a different wrapper each time you use h5, e.g.:

```
<div class="title-page">
  <h5>My Title</h5>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="other-page">
  <h5>My Title 2</h5>
</div>
```

And set margins accordingly:

```
.title-page h5 {
     margin: 10px;
}
.other-page h5 {
     margin: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: use this only if there are more occurences of h5 that share the same margin and padding. if that is not the case, it's better to use classes as @dampe said.

Answer (score 2):

**Using css classes.**

Ie.:  setting these in external stylesheet (or wherever you need..)

```
.BigHeading {font-size:2em; margin:1em;}
.MediumHeading {font-size:1em; margin:0.5em;}
```

and then in html markup you use it like:

```
<h5 class="BigHeading">This is a big heading!</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know the structure of the website, you might want to take a look at the design again to make sure h5 elements will not differ so much.

You can use a class for each different margin setting.

Answer (score 0):

Either use different h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, etc with different settings, or split them into classes:

```
h5 {
  background: #ff0000; /* All h5 inherits this and any properties in here. */
}

h5.small_padding {
  padding: 5px;
}

h5.big_padding {
  padding: 20px;
}

<h5 class="small_padding">Title</h5>
<h5 class="big_padding">Blah</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add classes or id to your DOM first, for example:

```
<h5 id="style1">title</h5>
<h5 class="style2">title</h5>
```

then use css to target these DOM:

```
h5#style1 { margin: 5px; }
h5.style2 { margin: 10px; }
```

note: # is for id, and . is for classes.
for more information, pls visit [this tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php).

Answer (score 0):

With the use of classes:

```
<h5 class="title">Foo</h5>
<h5 class="title margined">Bar<h5/>
<h5 class="brightTitle">Other</h5>

h5 {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
h5.title {
    color: Blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h5.margined {
    margin-bottom: 0.6em; 
}
h5.brightTitle {
    color:Red;
}
```

Foo would be blue, bold, and underlined.

Bar would be blue, bold, underlined, and have a margin.

Other would be red and underlined.

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/kHHAs/)